# Description of class attributes in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Where can I find a description of a class attribute (or if it's called instance variable) in keras? For instance `word_index` in `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`?

Example of use:

```
sentence = ['a', 'b', '{', 'c', '-']
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentence)
w = tokenizer.word_index
print(w)
```

I can't find it in the API at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for that attribute. The description of attributes in Python is usually done either as part of the class description itself, as part of the constructor documentation, when the attribute value is directly assign from there, or wrapping it into a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). In this case, looking at [the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/1.1.0/keras_preprocessing/text.py), none of those seem to apply. But this code:

```py
# note that index 0 is reserved, never assigned to an existing word
self.word_index = dict(
    list(zip(sorted_voc, list(range(1, len(sorted_voc) + 1)))))
```

Seems to suggest that it is a dict storing the index of each token, starting from one and sorted by frequency, which is the content of `sorted_voc` (and if `oov_token` is given it would be the first one).

If the attribute is meant to be usable outside of the class, it should have been documented properly though.